# SCNView overlay causes tearing on resize

Tags: macos, cocoa, sprite-kit, scenekit, metal

I'm using SceneKit to display a 3D scene (so far, a single quad), and the overlaySKScene to display a 2D overlay (which so far is just a SKNode with no geometry, though I had previously used a single SKLabelNode). It's a pretty simple view inside a bunch of nested NSSplitView. And during normal use, it works brilliantly. The problem comes when I try to resize the window or split view — I get areas of red leaking through my nice background, which disappear shortly after.

I'm running this on a 2016 MBP with a Radeon Pro 460, and captured this frame using Quicktime's screen capture: 
[image: The red tearing on resizing the view]

Disabling the overlay removes the red areas, which makes me think that it's the problem. Disabling the statistics bar or the scroller (a child view of the SCNView) do not have any impact. My most minimal SKScene subclass is defined as

```
@implementation TestOverlay
- (instancetype) initWithSize: (CGSize) size
{
    if( self = [super initWithSize: size] )
    {
        // Setup the default state
        self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Has anybody run into similar issues before? Annoyingly, the apple sample Fox2 doesn't have similar problems...

Comment: Are there constraints in place?  I am going to guess your Views ate not being resized when you change the window size

Comment: That was my thought too, though the view does catch up within a frame or two. The overlay scene seems to be the culprit, disabling it removes the effect completely, but the settings for the overlay should enable it to resize properly, and I'm not doing any drawing at all in the test above, so it doesn't make sense to be drawing the red regions.

Comment: It was an inappropriate use of a delegate method. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For true enlightenment, one needs to read the documentation carefully, then comment everything out and restore functionality one step at a time. And then read the documentation again.

In the discussion section of [-[SCNSceneRendererDelegate renderer:willRenderScene:atTime:]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate/1523483-renderer?language=objc#), the solution is obvious (emphasis mine):

> You should only execute Metal or OpenGL drawing commands (and any setup required to perform them) in this method—**the results of modifying SceneKit objects during this method are undefined**.

Which is exactly what I was doing. I had misread this as modifying geometry, so thought that assigning textures would be reasonable to do here (after all, "will" render means it hadn't started rendering yet, right?), and would therefore pick the most recently created texture. And unfortunately, before I decided that I needed an overlay, this actually works perfectly well! As soon as the overlay was added, however, the tearing appeared.

The correct place to update material properties seems to be **-[SCNSceneRendererDelegate renderer:updateAtTime]**. Use that to avoid silly bugs like this one folks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset SMC (System Management Controller). It helped me for solving a similar problem but with Autodesk Maya 2018 on MBP 2017 (Radeon 560).

So, shut down and unplug your MBP.

On the built-in keyboard, press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd> keys on the left side and press the <kbd>Power Button</kbd> and hold all of these down for 10 seconds, then release the keys.

Connect the power adapter and then turn the Mac on normally.

Hope this helps.

> P.S. In case it doesn't help, try to check/uncheck `Automatic graphics switching` option in `System Preferences`–`Energy Saver` to see if there's a difference.

Comment: No improvement, sadly. And doesn't explain why its only my code that does it.

Comment: Why your frame rate is so strange – 95fps?

Comment: I suspect that is due to to the resizing — the rest of the time, it sits neatly around 60fps. No luck with disabling automatic switching, and the Metal view is running with the discrete GPU.